# Nothing or anything

Tags: sentence-choice, negation

Sometimes I never know if I should say nothing or anything.

For example:
Should I say

> I don't have nothing to do

or

> I don't have anything to do

Comment: Thank you all. Nice explanations. I'm very happy I have found this site

Answer (score 5):

Standard English (from whichever country) does not allow another negative word (no, nothing, nobody, nowhere, never, etc) within the scope of "not": use the corresponding "any" form instead.

Many colloquial varieties of English all over the world do allow this, and many people say "I don't have nothing to do". But at the same time, many speakers don't use such forms, and some judge people harshly who do so.

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that.

Comment: @Era: Ain't nobody *never* gonna disagree with you there!

Comment: "I have nothing to do" is also a valid form.

Comment: Just to expand on "some judge people harshly who do so", double negatives like "don't have nothing" tend to be part of rural dialects (at least in the US) so some folks associate speaking that way with being uneducated or ignorant.

Comment: The chief problem for learner is not exactl that they don't understand this, but more that they think *anything* is a negative word (usually by extension from their own language where they would use a negative word such as *nothing* where we use a word with a positive meaning). So you could make your answer really helpful if you explain that *anything* has a positive meaning (would probably require an example) - otherwise these guys will just find it confusing!

Comment: But "anything" in this sense _is_ a negative word: it is obligatorily used in the context of "not". It has a different sense in a positive sentence.Is that what you're referring to, @Araucaria?

Comment: It's an NPI, but has a positive meaning. It occurs where other languages would have a negative word (pas, nada etc) Ss tend to think it is an emphatic form of *nothing*.

Comment: I don't see in what sense you regard _anything_ (in this meaning) as positive. If you mean that it doesn't neutralise the negative _not_, that is a artefact of the unreasonable belief that "a double negative makes a positive" - only in formal logic, or in English, would anybody maintain that.

Comment: As you know, I won't get your messages unless you @ me. How would you explain to students that *any* doesn't mean *no*?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing = not anything

You use the pronoun nothing to express an absence of things. As it already has a negative word "no" in it, you don't use another negative before or after it. So the sentence:

I have nothing to do = I don't have anything to do.

However, the "nothing" is stronger and more definite than "not anything".